# How many stored procedure calls per transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, transactions

I guess it's a bit rude to ask this question, as I should make an effort (more than googling) to figure it out myself, but maybe some one knows the answer off the top of his head.

How many stored procedure calls are made per transaction (MS SQL 2005/2008)? Say, I created a stored procedure which triggers on inserts and from within a Java application, I commit only once all the insert statements were sent. Does the stored procedure trigger at every insert or only after I commit? Or does it depends on how I set up the stored procedure?

Cheers,
Max

Comment: Are you talking about stored procedures or triggers?

Comment: Both in a way. The trigger is calling a stored procedure, so either I modify the trigger to fire only once per transaction or the stored procedure so it returns without doing anything unless a commit occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger will fire once for each INSERT statement.  So, the stored procedure will run each time the trigger runs.  The number of executions is not related to when a transaction is committed.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to change the trigger, so that it fires only at the end of the INSERT burst (i.e. the commit)?

Comment: No, an insert trigger is designed to fire when an INSERT statement is executed on the table.  However, with some extra work, you could avoid it.  You can look into INSTEAD OF triggers that can replace the work of the INSERT trigger (not sure if this would work for you).  Or, you have no trigger at all.  Then you would have to add a coding step somewhere else (just before the commit and maybe in the Java) that does the work you wanted to do in the trigger.

Comment: Good point. I start to question my design. The trigger was to indicate UPDATE/INSERT changes in a table. Since, I have total control over all the data changing applications, I might as well not go through the database to indicate a change at all and indicate a change directly via different message passing means. Thanks again.